# Yaml type-safe configuration in Spring using Kotlin Functional Style

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, yaml, configuration-files

I'm trying to follow the demo https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-kotlin-functional to create a new Spring Boot application using the annotation-free new approach, released in Spring Boot 2. My problem is how to continue to use Yaml files to configure my application, without using annotations? I would guess it would be something inside the Beans configuration but I dont find any documentation on that subject. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beans` dsl has an `env` property that you can use to retrieve any `environment` property defined in yaml, properties files or command line parameters:

```
fun beans() = beans {
    bean<SomeBeanThatNeedsConfig> { 
      SomeBeanThatNeedsConfig(env.getProperty("config.value"))
    }
}
```